# c++ string - assignment is crashing

Tags: c++, string, std

I'm currently developing a code in c++ and to be more "C++", I'm moving my char * to string.

By the way, I do have some issues to assign the value.

My code is crashing as soon as I am assigning a str to the std::string.

Here is the code.

```
    std::string str;

    std::cout << "Friendly\n";
    str.assign(LIBMTP_Get_Friendlyname(PulsDeviceMngr->device));
    if(str.empty())
        PulsDeviceMngr->devicename = "Not Defined";
    else {
        PulsDeviceMngr->devicename = str ;
        str.clear();
    }
```

I have also try to replace:

```
    str.assign(LIBMTP_Get_Friendlyname(PulsDeviceMngr->device));
```

by

```
    str = LIBMTP_Get_Friendlyname(PulsDeviceMngr->device);
```

LIBMTP_Get_Friendlyname can return NULL is there is not Friendlyname defined.

I'm lost.. it's the first time I'm using the string under c++
thx for your help

Comment: Maybe you should check to see if it's `NULL` before assigning?  I'm pretty sure you aren't allowed to assign a null pointer.

Comment: What type is `PulsDeviceMngr->devicename`?

Comment: LIBMTP resturn a char *

Comment: PulsDeviceMngr is a struct in which devicename is a string

Comment: Only reason here assign could fail is `LIBMTP_Get_Friendlyname(PulsDeviceMngr->device)` returning a NULL pointer.

Comment: Thx. it seems that it's coming from the fact that the value was NULL and I try to assign it. but i should have a way to get value and assign only if empte

Comment: @ravi: Or an otherwise undereferencable one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure there a friendly name defined, so that it doesn't return NULL. Also make sure LIBMTP_Get_Friendlynam() returns of type either string or char*.

Answer (score 0):

Your comment says:

> It seems that it's coming from the fact that the value was `NULL` and I try to `assign` it. but i should have a way to get value and assign only if empte[sic]

Your question says:

> `LIBMTP_Get_Friendlyname` can return `NULL` is there is not`Friendlyname` defined.

If you pass [`std::string::assign`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/string/string/assign/) a pointer, such as `NULL` it will attempt to use the C-String overload. The C-String overload will copy characters from the referenced array until it reaches a null-character. But your code has told it that the C-String is at address 0, when dereferenced that will segfault.

**The solution is to return `""` where you had previously returned NULL.**

This will ensure there is always a string to `assign`.